# How can put a program to print a specific XX grid?

Tags: java, loops

The question is same: How can put a program to print a specific XX grid ?
I only want to know how to print a XX grid in the code.

Example output must be this:

```
Type in the height: 5
Type in the width: 2

XX
XX
XX
XX
XX
```

---

```
import java.util Scanner;
public class Loops {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        while( height <= 1 || width <= 1 ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid height or width value");
            System.out.print("Type in the height");
            height= input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Type in the width:");
            width = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help ! Thanks .

Comment: If the answer below satisfies you, you may accept it

Answer (score 1):

When you have the `height` and the `width`, you just need to do 2 `for-i loops` to build the pattern

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    System.out.println();               // jump line
}
```